# Rotating robot towards direction of the ball

Tags: python, rotation, angle, lego-mindstorms, nxt

I would like to know is this method the right way to go about this?.I want to rotate my robot which is facing north to the direction where an object is in this case the red ball.

Below shows the grid and the position of the ball
[image]

And here is my code to this:

```
def turn_to(brick, new_x, new_y, old_x, old_y, angle):
    delta_x = new_x - old_x
    print delta_x
    delta_y = new_y - old_y
    print delta_y

    roboCturn = base * pi
    Circumference = diameter * pi

    if(angle > 315 or angle < 45):
        #tested
        if (delta_x < 0 and delta_y == 0):
            #180 degrees tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(180)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho      

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x == 0 and delta_y > 0):
            #90 degrees right tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x == 0 and delta_y < 0): 
            #90 degrees left tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y > 0):
            # degrees in 1st quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 4th quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y > 0):
            #degrees in 2nd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 3rd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        else:
            left.weak_turn(power=0, tacho_units=0)
            right.weak_turn(power = 0, tacho_units=0)

    elif(angle > 45 and angle < 135):
        #tested
        if (delta_x == 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #180 degrees tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(180)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho      

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y == 0):
            #90 degrees right tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y == 0): 
            #90 degrees left tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y > 0):
            # degrees in 1st quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 4th quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y > 0):
            #degrees in 2nd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 3rd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        else:
            left.weak_turn(power=0, tacho_units=0)
            right.weak_turn(power = 0, tacho_units=0)

    elif(angle > 135 and angle < 225):
        #tested
        if (delta_x > 0 and delta_y == 0):
            #180 degrees tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(180)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho      

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x == 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #90 degrees right tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x == 0 and delta_y > 0): 
            #90 degrees left tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y > 0):
            # degrees in 1st quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 4th quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y > 0):
            #degrees in 2nd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 3rd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        else:
            left.weak_turn(power=0, tacho_units=0)
            right.weak_turn(power = 0, tacho_units=0)

    elif(angle > 225 and angle < 315):
        #tested
        if (delta_x == 0 and delta_y > 0):
            #180 degrees tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(180)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho      

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y == 0):
            #90 degrees right tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x < 0 and delta_y == 0): 
            #90 degrees left tested
            angle_rad = math.radians(90)
            angle_deg = (angle_rad) * (180/pi)
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif (delta_x > 0 and delta_y > 0):
            # degrees in 1st quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif(delta_x > 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 4th quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), delta_x)
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            left.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            right.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif(delta_x < 0 and delta_y > 0):
            #degrees in 2nd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2(delta_y, (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 + ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        elif(delta_x < 0 and delta_y < 0):
            #degrees in 3rd quadrant tested
            angle_rad = math.atan2((math.fabs(delta_y)), (math.fabs(delta_x)))
            angle_deg = 90 - ((angle_rad) * (180/pi))
            print angle_deg
            distanceTurned = (angle_deg/360) * (roboCturn)
            numberRotations = (distanceTurned) / (Circumference)
            tachoUnits = (numberRotations) * tacho

            right.weak_turn(power=power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)
            left.weak_turn(power=-power, tacho_units=tachoUnits)

        else:
            left.weak_turn(power=0, tacho_units=0)
            right.weak_turn(power = 0, tacho_units=0)
```

i just want to know is this the right way to solve this? or is there an alternative because i would be passing in values based on the question i posted previously. Thanks

Regards
Edward

Comment: I think atan2 is quadrant aware so you can just `math.atan2(dy,dx)` ... i think at least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way too much math. Use [`math.atan2()`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.atan2) to get the desired angle and subtract it from π/2 to get the appropriate rotation.

Comment: but would the value change when let's say the robot is facing north now based on the image above is change to facing east or west or south

Comment: Yes. But the only thing that changes is the angle you subtract it from (0 for E, π for W, 3π/2 for S).

Comment: hey, would you mind giving me and example on this? i got confused counting the angles :/ sorry for the trouble

Comment: If you're facing E then you're at 0 and turning directly to the calculated angle requires turning clockwise the negative of that angle (`0 - a`). If you're facing N then you're at π/2 and you need to turn clockwise π/2 (to get back to 0) plus the negative of that angle (since we're now facing 0 after turning clockwise π/2) (`math.pi / 2 - a`). And so on.